# Best way to replace an array with its contents from inside an object

Tags: javascript

I'm given the following JavaScript object:

```
{
    name: [
        {
            "firstName":"First ",
            "lastName":"Last"
        }
    ],
    age: 21
}
```

The `name` property (or other similar complex props) are always provided as an object within an array, even though there can only ever be a single value.

I need to save the information as an object that looks like this (without the array around the value of the `name` property):

```
{ 
    name: { 
        firstName: 'First ',
        lastName: 'Last' 
    }, 
    age: 21
}
```

I need a generic function that doesn't reference a particular property name because that changes depending on the query. Here's my solution:

```
const object = {
    name: [{"firstName":"First ","lastName":"Last"}],
    age: 21
}
const data = {}

for (const property in object) {
    const value = object[property]
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        data[property] = value[0]
    } else {
        data[property] = value
    }
}
```

Which returns the properly formatted object.

My question is whether this is the most performant and/or most obvious way to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: The way the question is written it looks like you get the object in the very same form you say you want to return it; so either I'm missing something or the "most performant way" would be to return the same object you received. I think you need to add more detail, and context, to the question.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica In the desired result, the name parameter does't include the  array.

Comment: Thank you; maybe it is time for bed after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want abstraction over the entire object you could do something like this:

```js
const object1 = {
  name: [{"firstName":"First ","lastName":"Last"}],
  age: 21
}

const rebuildObject = (object) => Object.keys(object).reduce((result, key) => {
  const value = object[key];
  result[key] = Array.isArray(value) ? object[key][0] : value;
  
  return result;
}, {});

const newObject = rebuildObject(object1);
console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: Great, this returns the expected output... I like that you used a ternary expression, which is definitely an improvement on my if/else statement. I'm only somewhat familiar with the reduce method, I need to learn more about it to understand why it's better than the for loop in my example.

Comment: Small note to keep in mind that this is not a deep rebuild. So if you want to convert objects deeper in a different scope you have to expand the code. But I doubt that'is a good idea since currently the code will convert every array into a object. If you the code to check if the array has multiple Entries you could use a deep merge to join them into one object and use the first or last value as it's data.

Answer (score 1):

If the `name` array is guaranteed to `only ever have 1 object inside of it` and is `always an array`, you can do:

```
const data = {
    name: [
        {
            "firstName":"First ",
            "lastName":"Last"
        }
    ],
    age: 21
};

if(data.name.length === 0) {
    const newObj = {
        name: data.name[0],
        age: data.age 
    };
};

console.log(newObj); // { firstName: 'First ', lastName: 'Last', age: 21 }
```

### Edit

When `name` is actually any arbitray key name, you can do:

```
const data = {
    name: [
        {
            "firstName":"First ",
            "lastName":"Last"
        }
    ],
    age: 21
};

const objKeys = Object.keys(data);

console.log(objKeys) // > Array ["name", "age"]

let arbKey = objKeys.filter(objKey => objKey !== "age")[0];
console.log(arbKey); // > "name"

const newObj = {
    arbKey: data[arbKey][0],
    age: data.age
};

console.log(newObj); // > Object { arbKey: Object { firstName: "First ", lastName: "Last" }, age: 21 };
```

**Note**: This only works based on the object schema you have provided. If your actual code is different, you will need to tweak it.

Comment: Yes the array is guaranteed to only ever have 1 object, but the property name is arbitrary. It could be `name`, it could be `address`, it could be `theAnswerToEverything`. The original object is returned by an API that I don't control. That just means I can't use a solution that references a particular property by name.

Comment: I have updated my answer to accomodate for an arbitrary key name

Comment: Sorry, no that's still not quite right. _Any_ property name can be arbitrary, not just the property containing the array. So `objKey !== "age"` would not work in this example. Also, the object that is returned should retain the original property name. If look closely at the second object in my example, you'll see the output I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1):

this is a generic function that can serve what you need, call the function with the object and property name you want to transform.

```
function arrayToObject(object, property) {
  if(object[property] && Array.isArray(object[property])) {
    object[property] = object[property][0];
  }
  return object;
}



 //  let data = {
 //       name: [
 //           {
 //               "firstName":"First ",
 //               "lastName":"Last"
 //           }
 //       ],
 //       age: 21
 //   }

// console.log(arrayToObject(data, 'name'));

// { name: { firstName: 'First ', lastName: 'Last' }, age: 21 }
```

**update:**

in case we don't know the property name,
we can use this version.

```
function arrayToObject(object) {
  for(let key in object){
    if(Array.isArray(object[key])) {
      object[key] = object[key][0];
    }
  }
  return object;
}
```

Comment: If you look at @orangesquare 's comment under my answer, we don't know the key name of the inner object, so this function wouldn't work because it relies on knowing the name of the inner prop

Comment: @rantao, thanks for that notice, I updated my function incase of unknown property name

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = {
    name: [
        {
            "firstName":"First ",
            "lastName":"Last"
        }
    ],
    age: 21
}

a.name = a.name[0];
```